# Stopping Splash Screen to go under the navigation bar

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

I would like to use this splash screen but it keep going under the navigation bar.

[Splash img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4UkR.png)

How can I force it to fit on the screen while keeping the navigation bar?

```
   <style name="splashScreenTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>

</style>
```

Comment: Please add your `@drawable/splash`

Comment: What do you mean by adding my @drawable/splash ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Found one solution

```
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
```

to

```
 <item name="android:background">@drawable/splash</item>
```

Comment: You are life saver! So hard to even describe the issue and to get correct reply and finally I found yours!

Comment: The background remains set even after I change the theme back to AppTheme before `super.onCreate` ans `setContentView`.

Comment: @maxbeaudoin in order to reset it, I used        `<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>`
in the main the theme.

Comment: Life saver indeed!

Answer (score -1):

Your `@drawable/splash`should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:drawable="@color/black"/>

<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image" />
</item>
```

Answer (score -2):

Add this to the xml file of your splash screen activity.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/splash"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: My splash screen only use the style.xml. So I'm not sure how I can add these line inside style.xml

Comment: Create a new xml file for your splash screen and add the code above inside it