# Item in Android splash screen does not appear

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

The splash screen I'm building has three elements in it. One along the top, another in the center, and the third along the bottom. In short, an element with `android:gravity="bottom"` will not appear within the screen. I'm using an xml file in `res/drawable/` and I started with all the elements as `<item />`s.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@color/black" />

  <item android:width="100dp"
    android:height="30dp"
    android:drawable="@mipmap/rb_mark"
    android:gravity="center"/>

  <item android:width="375dp"
    android:height="48dp"
    android:drawable="@mipmap/upper_tread"
    android:gravity="top"/>

  <item android:width="375dp"
    android:height="48dp"
    android:drawable="@mipmap/lower_tread"
    android:gravity="bottom"/>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

I've tried using `<bitmap />` for the bottom image

```
<item android:id="@+id/lower_tread">
    <bitmap android:src="@mipmap/lower_tread" android:gravity="bottom" />
</item>
```

On a tip from I received elsewhere, I tried setting the minHeight attribute to 1 on the View and/or the specific element in the LaunchActivity. I also tried setting the View to full screen there as well.

```
public class LaunchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  protected Window window = getWindow();
  protected View rView = findViewById(R.id.lower_tread); // or android.R.id.content

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
      View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN 
    );
    rView.setMinimumHeight(1);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
  }
}
```

Again, the first two elements in the xml display as expected. But any thing with `android:gravity="bottom"` does not appear in the screen. What's happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my issue

```
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_launch</item>
```

needed to be

```
 <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_launch</item>
```

Also documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45247476/4206689)